# How to use Backbone Model to Multiple Views (in Multiple Files)?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have simple HTML page, where I want to show multiple views with same data. For that I created one Backbone Model with data and two views to render. All my models and views are separated in separate files. I want to use my model object in all views. So I don't have to make multiple ajax calls to the server for same data for my 2 views.

Here is my code

Model.js

```
var ModelData = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{
      Name: "ABC",
      Marks: 100
   }
});

var modelData= new ModelData();
```

View1.js

```
var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
      this.model = (HOW TO REFER MY MODEL Object ?)
   }
});
```

View2.js

```
var View2 = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
      this.model = (HOW TO REFER MY MODEL Object?)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName`, `attributes` and `events`.

So you should attach the model when you instantiate your views:

```
var v1 = new View1({ model: modelData });
var v2 = new View2({ model: modelData });
```

You should have a router or other object that takes care of instantiating your views. Whatever this thing is should keep track of the `modelData` model instance and then pass it to the views when instantiating them.